# Including @firebase/app in firebase functions package.json

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

After updating to the newest firebase SDK and tools

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I started getting the following error when trying to deploy my firebase functions:

```
TypeError: instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent is not a function
    at registerDatabase (/Users/jr/projects/docavea/functions/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15168:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jr/projects/docavea/functions/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15200:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at FirebaseNamespace.get [as database] (/Users/jr/projects/docavea/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:282:38)
```

I have found posts on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/714 and 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/717 and https://twitter.com/plane1113/status/1203009025232654336 that suggests various solutions for this problem, but none of them worked for me, except to include @firebase/app. Some suggested that this was cause by having @firebase/app somewhere in my project but when I ran 
`npm ls @firebase/app` I got

```
    functions@ /Users/jr/projects/docavea/functions

└── (empty)
```

So my question is: What is @firebase/app and is it a problem to include it in my firebase functions package.json

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
        "build": "tsc",
        "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
        "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
    },
    "main": "lib/src/index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@firebase/app": "^0.5.0",
        "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "firebase-admin": "^8.9.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.13.1"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.3.2"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "tslint": "^5.20.1",
        "typescript": "^3.7.4"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

Comment: I've never had to use "@firebase/app" before, and I've done a lot of stuff with Cloud Functions. Don't know why it would ever be necessary for deployment.  Please edi the question to show the code you're trying to deploy - we should be able to reproduce exactly the issue as you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer the question `@firebase/app` is a module that is part of the Firebase Web SDK (you get it by `npm install firebase`) and never needs to be manually installed, and should not be installed at all for `firebase-admin`.

So in a nutshell, here is what's going on with this error, in general: `firebase-admin` has a dependency called `@firebase/database`, which is shared with the Firebase Web SDK.  A recent release of `@firebase/database` had some changes that caused it to not work if used with an older version of `@firebase/app`.

So basically, it should work if you have either (1) no `@firebase/app` or (2) a current `@firebase/app`.  Your error sounds most likely to be an existing outdated `@firebase/app`.

I know you said you don't seem to have `@firebase/app` in your project but since it seems like the most likely cause, I'm wondering if you have it in a parent directory. (It's installed as part of the Firebase Web SDK, as in `npm install firebase`.) Most firebase functions (if you use firebase init) are set up in a `/functions` subdirectory of the main project repo, with its own package.json, and the rest of the project is one level up and has another package.json.  And that looks like it might be your dir structure?

In that case, running `npm ls` inside `/functions` will turn up an empty result, but if you go up to the parent dir (that contains the other package.json), it will show up. Node will go up a level if it doesn't find a package at the current one.  See if you can ensure both levels are clean from any `@firebase/app`, delete both node_modules dirs, reinstall. If you do need it in the top level (for Firebase Web SDK), make sure it is upgraded the most current `firebase` (7.6.1).

As a last resort, maybe check to see if `firebase` is npm installed globally somehow.

If you definitely don't have `@firebase/app` at any level of your project and it's still failing, this is a bug we should look into.

Sorry that's a lot of info! Hope that wasn't too much. TLDR: I think you do probably have @firebase/app in your project root dir? If not, please file an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Christina Holland answer I investigated a bit further. When I ran `npm ls @firebase/app` in my Angular folder (functions is a subfolder of that) I got:

```
    └─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase@7.6.1
      └── @firebase/app@0.5.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: firebase@>= 5.5.7 <7, required by @angular/fire@5.2.1
```

I then updated @angular/fire to the newest version. It didn't change the @firebase/app version, but it removed the error:

```
└─┬ firebase@7.6.1
  └── @firebase/app@0.5.0
```

After that I could remove @firebase/app from my a functions package.json and I could deploy without any errors.

I don't understand what happens here, but the problem is solved and maybe it can help some other developer with this problem.